# Vigenere cipher in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vigenere-cipher

I implemented the Vigenere cipher in haskell as a part of exercises for  Haskell programming from first principles.

Though the code isn't all that long, I feel it could use some refactoring to simplify things (I feel the code I wrote is ugly). One caveat: string inputs should all be in **uppercase**.

The `vigenere` function should be applied like so:

```
vignere "ALLY" "MEET AT DAWN"
```

which will create the output:

```
"MPPRAEOYWY"
```

As it stands, here's the code I implemented:

```
import Data.Char

-- exercise chapter 11
encode :: Char -> Int
encode x = ord x - ord 'A'

decode :: Int -> Char
decode x = chr (x + ord 'A')

shift :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Char -> Char
shift f x ch =  decode $ f (encode ch) x `mod` 26

rightShift :: Int -> Char -> Char
rightShift = shift (+)

leftShift :: Int -> Char -> Char
leftShift = shift (-)

encodeString :: String -> [Int]
encodeString str = map encode str

type Secret = String
type PlainText = String
type CipherText = String

vignereString :: Secret -> PlainText -> String
vignereString secret plain = take len $ cycle secret
                          where len = length $ concat $ words plain

vignereCode :: Secret -> PlainText -> [Int]
vignereCode secret plain = encodeString $ vignereString secret plain


vignere :: Secret -> PlainText -> CipherText
vignere secret plain =
  zipWith rightShift code plainNoSpace
  where code = vignereCode secret plain
        plainNoSpace = concat $ words plain

unvignere :: Secret -> CipherText -> PlainText
unvignere secret cipher =
  zipWith leftShift code cipherNoSpace
  where code = vignereCode secret cipher
        cipherNoSpace = concat $ words cipher
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a nice solution, but very long for a relatively simple task.

First, note that the cipher is called "Vigenère", so `vignere` would be considered a misspelling.

The type definitions…

> ```
> type Secret = String
> type PlainText = String
> type CipherText = String
> ```

… provide an illusion of type safety, where there actually isn't any.  They are all just `String`s.

All of the helper functions (`encode`, `decode`, `shift`, `rightShift`, `leftShift`, and `encodeString`) could just be reduced to a single function:

```
import Data.Char (chr, ord)

shift :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Char -> Char -> Char
shift op offset ch = numToChar $ (charToNum ch) `op` (charToNum offset)
  where
    charToNum ch = ord ch - ord 'A'
    numToChar n = chr $ (n `mod` 26) + ord 'A'
```

Hiding the `charToNum` and `numToChar` helpers makes it easier to see what calls what.

With the generalized `shift` function defined, the enciphering and deciphering routines could each be one-liners:

```
vigenere :: String -> String -> String
vigenere secret = zipWith (shift (+)) (cycle secret) . concat . words

unvigenere :: String -> String -> String
unvigenere secret = zipWith (shift (-)) (cycle secret) . concat . words
```

Here, I've written them using point-free style to emphasize the fact that `vigenere secret` acts as an enciphering filter on the text.

Comment: shift ought not to take offset and ch in the wrong order just because (-) and zip argument orders are inconvenient. I'd instead replace (-) with subtract.

Comment: ah I guess I shouldn't have split functionality to so many little functions which actually ended up making things complex. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: @Gurkenglas Actually, placing `offset` before `ch` was a deliberate design decision to facilitate currying. You can write a Caesar cipher decipherer as `unCaesar = map $ shift (-) 'B'`.

Comment: Right, and if the arguments were the right way round you could still do `unCaesar = map $ shift subtract 'B'`. The offset still goes first, but it is passed to the first argument of the operation, not the second.

Comment: @Gurkenglas But then `'B'` would be the `ch`, rather than the `offset`.

Comment: @200_success no, it would be `shift op offset ch = numToChar $ (charToNum offset) \`op\` (charToNum ch)`, where `'B'` goes in the place of `offset`, so `charToNum 'B'` goes into the first argument of `subtract`.